# Error al instalar java alternatives, en Linux CentOS RedHat

Tags: linux, centos, red-hat

descargue este archivo: jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar, es un comprimido que contiene los comandos de java para linux ya tengo ese archivo .tar en la carpeta opt, y ya lo descomprimí, pero ahora para instalarlo debo usar este comando: alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java 2

este comando me va a instalar los comandos de java que se encuentran en la carpeta que acabo de descomprimir, y los instala en la carpeta usr/bin/java, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el comando me aparece este error:
numeric priority expected in /var/lib/alternatives/java
unexpected line in /var/lib/alternatives/java: jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java

[image: En esta imagen se aprecia el error que me sale al ejecutar el comando mencionado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLUCIONADO] Pude solucionar el problema, resulta que me fui a la ruta que me da el error con ayuda del programa winSCP, y una vez ahi me di cuenta que había ya 3 archivos: java, javac y jar, entonces pensé que eso era lo que estaba impidiendo instalar java, ya que probablemente lo había instalado antes y no lo sabía, entonces los borré y los respalde por si acaso, volvi a intentar instalar y ahora si se pudo.